# IQueryable - how to get all unique Years from db set?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I got a DbSet, where the model with the DateTime field "Date", and I want to get all the unique years. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Distinct` would be another way

```
var uniqueYears = db.YourDbSet.Select(t => t.Date.Year).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use group by query with linq.

```
var uniqueYears = db.Table.GroupBy(c=> c.Date.Year).Select(c=> c.Key).ToList();
```